# Wordpress Theme Slider Error illegal offset string

Tags: php, wordpress, revolution-slider

I am working on a wordpress site where the theme was recently updated. The Apache error console is reporting an illegal string offset error for the revolution slider included with the theme. I have looked through the code, and the database.

The errors are as follows:

```
    [Fri Aug 14 15:47:42.523359 2015] [:error] [pid 3101] [client 66.249.83.171:27930] PHP Warning: Illegal string offset 'description' in /nas/wp/www/cluster-40875/wkog/wp-content/themes/purity/includes/slider.php on line 43
    [Fri Aug 14 15:47:42.523371 2015] [:error] [pid 3101] [client 66.249.83.171:27930] PHP Warning: Illegal string offset 'link' in /nas/wp/www/cluster-40875/wkog/wp-content/themes/purity/includes/slider.php on line 32
    [Fri Aug 14 15:47:42.523383 2015] [:error] [pid 3101] [client 66.249.83.171:27930] PHP Warning: Illegal string offset 'image' in /nas/wp/www/cluster-40875/wkog/wp-content/themes/purity/includes/slider.php on line 33
    [Fri Aug 14 15:47:42.523396 2015] [:error] [pid 3101] [client 66.249.83.171:27930] PHP Warning: Illegal string offset 'image' in /nas/wp/www/cluster-40875/wkog/wp-content/themes/purity/includes/slider.php on line 36
    [Fri Aug 14 15:47:42.523537 2015] [:error] [pid 3101] [client 66.249.83.171:27930] PHP Warning: Illegal string offset 'description' in /nas/wp/www/cluster-40875/wkog/wp-content/themes/purity/includes/slider.php on line 38
    [Fri Aug 14 15:47:42.523553 2015] [:error] [pid 3101] [client 66.249.83.171:27930] PHP Warning: Illegal string offset 'link' in /nas/wp/www/cluster-40875/wkog/wp-content/themes/purity/includes/slider.php on line 39
    [Fri Aug 14 15:47:42.523565 2015] [:error] [pid 3101] [client 66.249.83.171:27930] PHP Warning: Illegal string offset 'description' in /nas/wp/www/cluster-40875/wkog/wp-content/themes/purity/includes/slider.php on          line 41
```

The Code in question is below:

```
    <div id="slider" class="flexslider vntd-block inner">
    <ul class="slides">
    <?php 
    $slides = get_option_tree( 'slider_slider', $option_tree, false, true, 1 );
    if($slides)
    foreach( $slides as $slide ) {
        echo '<li>';
        if($slide['link']) { echo '<a href="'.$slide['link'].'">'; }
        if(strpos($slide['image'],'veented.com')) {
            $img_url = $slide['image'];
        } else {
            $img_url = crop_img($slide['image'],960,get_option_tree('slider_height'));
        }
        echo '<img src="'.$img_url.'" title="'.$slide['description'].'" alt></a>';
        if($slide['link']) { echo '</a>'; }

        if($slide['description']){
            echo '<p class="flex-caption">';
            echo '<span class="slide-caption">'.$slide['description'].'</span>';
            echo '</p>';
        }

        echo '</li>';
    }           
    ?>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I've searched here, Google, various blogs, the support forum for the theme. I have reinstalled the theme, I have disabled all of the plugins and enabled them sequentially. the PHP Version on the server is PHP 5.5.9

I have tried a number of things but I don't know why the slider on the front page is not displaying images.

Comment: what's the value of `$slide` are you sure it's an array all the time

Comment: I see where you are going with this, I don't think that it is always an array, or maybe not defined as one like it should. I am not able to check immediately, I will look later this evening and check back in.